# after pseudo element not working in webview

Tags: android, html, css, ionic-framework

I am developing a mobile application with ionic and using `::after` pseudo element. It is working fine in browser view itself in my computer. However, when i deploy the app into device, the **red triangle** is missing from the view. Anyone know what the problem is? Or is there any other alternative solution that i could apply?

Note: I am deploying into Android application with KitKat. Not really sure if it does not work in other version of Android or IOS.

Fiddler: [Click here](http://jsfiddle.net/dvv7bg76/53/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried a solution where you do not use a Pseudo element? Give this a try,

```
<div class="image">
<span class="red"></span>
<img src="http://placeimg.com/400/100/any">
</div>
```

CSS

```
.image{
    position:relative;
}
.red{
    content:'';
    width: 0; 
    height: 0; 
    border-right: 50px solid transparent;
    border-top: 50px solid #f00;
    position:absolute;
    left:0;
    top:0;
}
img{
    width:100%;
}
```